# Colors in plotly bar graph R

Tags: r, plotly, bar-chart, color-scheme, stacked-chart

See also [Custom colors in R Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601464/custom-colors-in-r-plotly?noredirect=1&lq=1)

When using a variable for color in a plotly bar graph.
How do you change the default color scheme?

```
    library(plotly)
    library(dplyr)

p <- ggplot2::diamonds %>% count(cut, clarity) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~cut, y = ~n, color = ~clarity) %>%
  layout(barmode = "stack") 

p
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [custom colors in R Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601464/custom-colors-in-r-plotly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`colors` argument of `plot_ly` takes a vector of length numbers of categories:

```
p <- ggplot2::diamonds %>% count(cut, clarity) %>%
   plot_ly(x = ~cut, y = ~n, color = ~clarity, colors = rainbow(10)) %>%
   layout(barmode = "stack") 
p
```